# Run graphical process in Docker container, detach and reconnect to the running GUI

Tags: python, docker, spyder

Let's say I have some computations in Python that take a long time, and are run from the Spyder IDE so the results can be easily inspected and used for further work afterwards.

I want to run the Spyder process inside a Docker container that is hosted on a server machine (i. e. not the same machine I'm sitting in front of). I have already seen that it is possible to run e. g. LibreOffice and Chrome like that, so this should be possible. But these processes were not kept alive when the user detached from the container.

Now the question is: is there a way to open a Spyder process within a Docker container, start the computations manually, detach from the Docker container, and afterwards reconnect to the container so I return to the still running Spyder GUI to be able to inspect the outcome of the computations and keep working with them?

To keep it simple for the users (which would be multiple people, but each with their own container), I would not want to have to save the computation results to a file a re-read them for further processing.

With IPython, I could probably simply use screen to keep the interpreter alive. But I would not know how to achieve the same thing with Spyder. Can I maybe somehow "connect" Spyder to a remote IPython interpreter?

**The solution:**

Thanks to @JanSuchotzki, I was able to get a X11-VNC-server-container running alongside a client container where Spyder is installed and that can use the server container for displaying graphics. After additionally setting an environmental variable `USER`, I'm able to run Spyder successfully. Only the screen size of the X11-server needs to be adjusted not to cut off the edge of the Spyder GUI, then everything works great!

Comment: is spyder this https://hub.docker.com/r/viktran/spyder/ ?

Comment: @user2915097 I don't know, since the repo doesn't tell anything; but if it contains the right program, I'm pretty sure it's just for starting it from a Docker container, but not really suitable for my application, sorry.

Comment: Try to add `-e LANG=C.UTF-8` when you call `docker run`. This will set the language settings to UTF8. There are no special locals (e.g. en-US) installed in the debian image. I would guess that it will solve your problem. When inside the container you can check with `locale` what the language settings are. I'll update the Dockerfiles for the images soon. So they will already set the locals properly.

Comment: @JanSuchotzki I tried your suggestion, but it did not change the situation. But I looked at the Spyder sources, and it appeared that the problem was that no environment variable `USER` was set inside the client container. So I did `export USER=xclient`, and afterwards Spyder was started successfully! The only thing now is: the Spyder GUI is "wider" that the display I get with VNC, and the right part of the GUI is cut off. Vertically, I can scroll the VNC client. So I guess the problem is with the screen size in the x11server container. Do you know how the screen size can be adjusted in there?

Comment: @JanSuchotzki Nevermind, I found out how it can be done :-) I will let you know how it went, and accept your answer!

Comment: I'm not sure how "run from the Spyder IDE" leads to "the results can be easily inspected and used for further work afterwards". I would expect dumping the results into a file (where you can `tail` and `grep` it even while it runs) or a database (where you can query it while it runs, as long as you commit frequently) would be a much more effective way of accomplishing both of those.

Comment: Not to mention much more reliable. A Spyder crash would result in losing all your data, wouldn't it?

Comment: @jpmc26 That, of course, is true. And if I would only use it myself, I would probably do it that way. But since I have multiple users for that, most of them also Matlab users and not-too-passionate tinkerers but rather pure users, I decided this would be the easiest way for them to start and to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running on a remote machine you might want to go with something like VNC. That basically means your container running Spyder also serves as a VNC-Server. Now you can attach via VNC-Client to the container and check what the current state is (interact with your IDE).

This will also work in a multi-user setup assuming each container, or better to say the VNC-server running inside, works on another port. Then you can simply distinguish the different containers by port.

I have created a base-image for running an debian based container with X-Server and VNC-Server. You can have a look on my [Docker-Hub Account](https://hub.docker.com/u/suchja/). There you will find an image for client and for server.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I originally wanted not to have the overhead of a VNC setup. But if there is already an existing solution by yours that only has to be adapted for my needs (regarding the additional software that needs to be installed), I will definitely try and tell you how it went!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sypder, but I think you'll want to start by looking at the Docker docs regarding [networking](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) and [exec](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/).

Another thought: If you can tell Spyder to run as a server, you could connect a client via an exposed port.

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I know that a remote IPython kernel on a server machine can be accessed from a client machine running Spyder, but I'm not sure whether a command can be executed and kept running after the client has disconnected from the kernel. This could even be something that is explicitly not desired by the developers. I will try, and tell you how it went!